# <input type="checkbox"> vs <div role="checkbox">

Tags: html, css, checkbox

To add checkbox it is most common practice to use `<input type="checkbox">` while I can see that youtube and gmail don't use that to create checkboxes. 
Instead they use `<div role="checkbox" aria-checked="true">`

Could you explain why it is not the most common practice to create checkboxes the same way as these companies do `(using <div role="checkbox">)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular checkbox **just works**. It is intrinsically checkboxy.

A div doesn't. A div is a generic container. To make it work like a checkbox you have to:

- add it to the tab order
- style it
- add JavaScript to make it interactive

  - ensure that JS works with a mouse
  - and a trackpad
  - and a keyboard
  - and a touch screen
  - and various other inputs
- convince screen readers to announce it as a checkbox
- probably other stuff I haven't thought about

… and all in all the different web browsers out there.

In order to get more flexibility about the look and feel of checkboxes you need to do an enormous amount of work.

It is much safer and simpler to just use the checkbox built into HTML.

---

So in short:

> Could you explain why it is not the most common practice to create checkboxes the same way as these companies do

Because the cost is high and the benefit is low.

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: add it to the tab order - is it not adding just one attribute ? - not big deal
style it - that exactly the reason why I want to use it so I have full power over it
and other reasons you mentioned would be say 50-100 lines of JS and it could be done in form of a micro library,

and in return I would get full power how I want my checkboxes to look like so I would definitely go for it

Comment: how is benefit low ?
I get full control how my checkboxes look like, that's low benefit? 
Also gmail and youtube seem to not think it's low benefit and I would like to do things same as them. Could you point me how I can learn how to do that?

Comment: "I get full control how my checkboxes look like, that's low benefit? — You might value it highly. Most people don't.

Comment: "Also gmail and youtube seem to not think it's low benefit then" — Google has a LOT of money to spend on getting things like this to work (including all the cross browser / device testing).

Comment: Ok I understand your argument. But if I wanted to do things like they do, where can I find info how to do that ?

Comment: @user3784950 Quentin just gave you a list of things you need to consider. Start by googling them